# Textfield Keyboard Bug - Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, textfield, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

my problem is this:

I have an app where the user enters how many percent he wants to save in a textfield.

[image: Screen initial state]

But when he touches the first time to fill the field, here's what happens: In addition to titanium not respect the `KeyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD` can not even put numbers or letters in the field, it looks like the pointer is lost in transition textfield of the position ...

[image: First Touch]

When I click again, it works correctly ... I may be wrong, but I think it has is because of when the keyboard appears, the textfield is nearest the top, thus making the keyboard pointer get lost, or something of the genre, because when the textfield does not move, it works perfectly as seen below.

[image]

Comment: what is your code? It looks like the initial focus is not fired on the correct textfield

Comment: this is my code: http://pastebin.com/7ZFfQb8T

Comment: that is correct code, but how do you invoke the focus event

Comment: what is located around the code. How is it nested. I need context

Comment: hello friend, I managed to run it another way: I added the direct textfield in xml ... still do not know the cause and how to fix the bug, but getting to work this otherwise .. .Since longer required!